# Binary file to text file and text file to binary

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project with files.
Part 1 of the project was to add / remove and sort some obejcts into text file, so I've already implemented those functions. 
Now Part 2 is to support Binary files as well - Means to add / remove and sort binary files.
My thinking is to have some "magic function" that convert binary file to text file, than to use my function above (because they support only text files), do whatever asks - add \ remove obejcts; Than to convert it again with the "magic function" from text file to binary file.
Every line inside my text file is an Object, called 'Candidate'. It has the following fields: string id,string name,string last name,string party
for example the 1st line looks like:
201,Donald,Trump,Republican
Any suggestion where to find this "magic function"?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Search Google for "base64 encoding".

Comment: I don't think that would be in the spirit of the requirement. The reason to use binary files is because they make it easier to add and remove objects.

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst so what do you suggest ?

Comment: Given that all of your data fields are string data, there would really be no difference between a 'text' and 'binary' representation of each record, except one you impose yourself, such as (1) make the fields (and thus the records) fixed size, or (2) preface each field with a binary length count and perhaps start each record with a  binary length count. These are only a few possibilities; there could be may other ways to make your file "binary".

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a general way of converting between text and binary data because you need to know what the data *means*, and this isn't clear, especially in the case of binary data.

Your class already knows what your data means, so only your class could reliably read itself as text and write itself as binary, or vice versa. But once you have implemented reading and writing as text or binary in your class, the need for conversion goes away.

I'm fairly sure that implementing reading and writing as text or binary in your class is what you were being asked to do in the first place.

Your class contains only `std::string`s. There is no standard way of writing them as binary, but one way is to write the length first, and then write the content:

```
void WriteString(const std::string& s, std::ofstream& os)
{
    size_t size = s.size();
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(size_t));
    os.write(s.c_str(), size);
}
```

The reverse process of reading means reading the length first, and then the content. You can't read the content straight into a `std::string` because its memory buffer isn't guaranteed to be contiguous, so you need to use a `std::vector<char>` as an intermediary:

```
std::string ReadString(std::ifstream& is)
{
    size_t size;
    is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&size), sizeof(size_t));
    std::vector<char> buffer(size);
    is.read(&buffer[0], size);
    return std::string(&buffer[0], size);
}
```

Now to write or read your `Candidate` objects as binary, you just need to use these two functions to write or read the fields one at a time:

```
void Candidate::Write(std::ofstream& os) const
{
    WriteString(id, os);
    WriteString(name, os);
    WriteString(last_name, os);
    WriteString(party, os);
}

void Candidate::Read(std::ifstream& is)
{
    id = ReadString(is);
    name = ReadString(is);
    last_name = ReadString(is);
    party = ReadString(is);
}
```

You will need a default constructor for your `Candidate` class to create "empty" objects for reading, and you will probably want to write the number of candidates at the top of the file so you know how many to read back.

There is a lot more to binary files than this - you will probably want to implement random access to really get the benefits - but this should get you started.